# "Could not get an RGB, double buffered visual" from glxgears when using Nvidia on-demand | Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I used to daily drive Ubuntu on my old computer. I recently purchaced a "new" computer with an Nvidia gpu as well as the integrated intel graphics. The 'new' system is a Dell
E6530 with an i7-3740QM, a NVS 5200M, 12GB RAM, and a 500GB HDD. It runs driver version 390.144 on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. On windows you can set low powered programs (e.g. Chrome)
to run on the intel gpu and high powered programs (e.g. Videogames/CAD) to run on the Nvidia gpu. On linux this should also be the case, but if I change the prime server to
Nvidia On-Demand, which should give the desired GPU switching effect, I can't run any 3D applications, like glxgears. If I try running glxgears, the process will not start
and reports that it "could not get an RGB, double buffered visual" when trying to run. If I have the Xserver setting set to "Nvidia (High performance)" or "Intel (Power
saving)" glxgears and other 3D apps run just fine.

STEPS TO REPRODUCE:

1. Obtain system with NVS 5200M (this is the only system I own with an Nvidia GPU s this may be a problem with any 390 compatible GPU
2. Do a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
3. Using the additional drivers thing, install the propriatary drivers version 390 (340 wouldn't work for me)
4. Open the Nvidia control pannel and under "PRIME Profiles" choose "Nvidia On-Demand"
5. Install "mesa-utils" for glxgears
6. Run glxgears
7. Behold! My error!

PC Specs:
Dell E6530

CPU - i7-3740QM

GPU - intel HD 4000

GPU - NVS 5200M

RAM - 12GB DDR3

Drive: 500GB Seagate laptop drive

Random side question:
Are there going to be drivers for 12th gen intel processers as well?

Comment: Indeed, "on-demand" doesn't work in systems of that vintage (or most at all).